# Reading and Parsing CSV File in Apache Cordova App

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a csv file that I want to process in my cordova app. I know how to find and open files, but no idea how to read the file and parse the content as csv. My research on the web did not bring any result so far. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spent two seconds on Google with "javascript parse csv" to find: http://papaparse.com